# React Web App Routing Works on Desktop (incl. Mobile Dev View), but not on Mobile Browsers

Tags: reactjs, mobile, web-applications, material-design, react-router-dom

I'm really stuck on a problem with a React web app I'm building. I'm using the array.map() method to dynamically create dropdowns, and I'm finding that everything works beautifully on desktop browsers (including in the mobile view of Chrome dev tools), but not on actual mobile browsers. I would really appreciate your thoughts!

### **Expected Behavior**

I expect the dropdowns to populate, usually from an array of objects. Then, when the user clicks on one of the items in the dropdown menu, it will either trigger (1) a function or (2) a link to another part of the React App. Note that I'm using react-router-dom to handle routing.

### **Observed Behavior on Mobile Browsers**

The dropdowns populate correctly, but they malfunction when I select from among the options (see Figure 1).
[image: Observed behavior on mobile browsers]

This behavior is observable when the dropdown selection triggers both a  (react-router-dom Component) and calls a function. In the limited cases when the function is called correctly, the correct parameters *are passed* and the function does execute correctly.

### **Code Snippits**

**This is an example of the code I'm using to generate the list of links.** It is a simple React functional component that serves as the header to all settings pages in my app, and the  Component is part of a [React MaterializeCSS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-materialize) library, which seems to be working fine.:

```js
const SettingsHeader = () => {

    let { url } = useRouteMatch();
    
    const { userAccess, styleItem, headerStyle, updateHeader, theme } = useContext(SettingsContext);

    const options = userAccess.length ? (
      userAccess.sort().map(permission => {
        // Returns an object with details needed to build the component via a Settings Context function.
        let details = styleItem(permission);
        return (
          <Link
            key={permission}
            to={`${url}${details.link}`}
            onClick={() => updateHeader(permission)}
          >
            <Icon className={theme.text}>{details.icon}</Icon>
            <span className={theme.text}> {details.text}</span>
          </Link>
        );
      })
    ) : (
      <h4 className="grey-text">
        <Icon>warning</Icon> You don't have permission to edit any settings.
      </h4>
    );
    
    return (
      <h4 className={theme.text}>
        <i className="material-icons">{headerStyle.icon}</i> {headerStyle.text}
        <Dropdown
          options={{ ... }}
          trigger={
            <Button className={"right " + theme.themeColor} node="button">
              Views
            </Button>
          }
        >
          {options}
          <a href="#!">
            <Icon className="grey-text">close</Icon>
            <span className="grey-text"> Close</span>
          </a>
        </Dropdown>
      </h4>
    );
}
```

This is an example of the code I'm using to generate a list of theme options, each of which calls a function in a React Context Component I'm using in many places in the App:

```js
const ThemeSettings = () => {

  // Brings in Theme update function from SettingsContext
  const { changeTheme, theme } = useContext(SettingsContext);

  // Array of possible themes.
  const themesList = ['Burnt Orange', 'Chrome', 'Deep Purple', 'Earth', 'Fresh Green', 'Green', 'Maroon', 'Navy', 'Pink', 'Red', 'Royal Blue', 'Teal']

  const themeOptions = themesList.map(theme => {
    let themeObject = getTheme(theme);

    return (
      <a href="#!" key={theme} onClick={(e) => changeTheme(e, theme) }>
        <Icon className={themeObject.text}>style</Icon>
        <span className={themeObject.text}> {theme}</span>
      </a>
    )
  });

  return (
    <Dropdown
      options={{ ... }}
      trigger={
        <Button className={"left " + theme.themeColor} node="button">
          Themes
        </Button>
      }
    >
      { themeOptions }
      <a href="#!">
        <Icon className="grey-text">close</Icon>
        <span className="grey-text"> Close</span>
      </a>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
```

Thanks very much for giving this a look!

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/6444#event-2671340700) MaterializeCSS bug for devices running iOS-13.

I was only able to find one workaround available at time of writing, mentioned by [Falk](https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/issues/924) in [this issue thread](https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/issues/924):

> To fix it, I had to check out the #v1-dev branch of
>   https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize, build it with grunt release
>   and use the materialize.js in /dist folder for my project.

Comment: That is a select issue, asker is querying a dropdown issue. They are different (albeit connected) elements in materializecss.